# ASP.NET MVC model nesting routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

Consider an ASP.NET MVC application with two models: let's say `Company` and `Person`. Each company has a list of persons. Each person belongs to one company only.

If you set up the model and use Visual Studio to generate the controllers/views, you get the ability to edit the companies at `/Company/{id}` etc. and the ability to edit the persons at `/Person/{id}` etc.

But I want it to be such that you can only add a person inside a company, i.e. you would edit the persons at `/Company/{id}/Persons/{id}`.

How can I set up this sort of routing in ASP.NET MVC 5?

---

EDIT:

So I did this in my routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CompanyPerson",
    url: "Company/{CompanyId}/Person/{PersonId}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Index", PersonId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Company",
    url: "Company/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

but it still isn't working. If I go to `/Company/7/Person` I get an index of persons, but `/Company/7/Person/Create` just gives the same index, and the "**Create New**" link points to `/Person/Create` instead of `/Company/7/Person/Create`

Is there just a way to set up all the routes explicitly, like Node or most other MVC frameworks?

Comment: So you just want to mess around with the URL?

Comment: Yes, and the person should automatically be associated with the current company.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work the way you're thinking.  The reason is that you have two different controllers, `Company` and `Person`.  You can't call both of them at the same time.

You are going to have to decide whether you want to edit a person at the `Person` controller, or edit them at the `Company` controller.  Personally, I'd edit the person at the person level, but that will mean your `Person.Edit` method will have to take the `companyId` as well as the `personId`.

So you would then create a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CompanyPerson",                                // Route name
    "Company/{companyId}/Person/{personId}",        // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Person", action = "Edit" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then your `Person.Edit` method would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int companyId, int personId) {}
```

EDIT:

You are going to have to use constraints to do what you want.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CompanyPerson",
    url: "Company/{companyId}/Person/{personId}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Index", PersonId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new {personId = @"\d+" }
);
```

However, this now means you can do `/Company/7/Person/15/Create`, and that just won't make any sense.  The `personId` will simply get ignored.

As for why your Create Link isn't working, is because of the id being before the action.  You'll also need another route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CompanyPerson",
    url: "Company/{companyId}/Person/Create",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Create" }
);
```

and this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Person", new { companyId = Model.companyId })
```

It would be a lot easier if you just stuck to the Id after the action.  You also need to be careful of capitalizing variable names, as these are C# variables and are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking of.

Comment: Sorry. It still isn't working. Give me a minute and I'll update the question.

Comment: @ian93 - It's not working because you completely changed it to something else.  You can't make personId optional if you have something coming after it, the matching pattern won't be able to figure it out

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't realize you couldn't make it optional if there was something after it. Sorry!

Comment: @ian93 - well, you can if you use constraints to ignore the route if it's not numeric, like I did above.. but then you need a separate route to handle the Create case where no id is present.